# How to zip selected multiple folders one after another in java

Tags: java, file, io, zip, apache-commons

I am trying to zip multiple folders using Java. Below is my code.

```
if (CompressType.ZIP == zip){
    File f = null;
    for (File serlectFile : serlectFiles){
         f = new File(serlectFile.getAbsolutePath());
         filePath = f;
         System.out.println("NIO Folders 1122 : " + filePath);
         new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                   compressFolder.createZip(filePath.getPath(), destination.getPath());
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Backup Created .....", "Alert", 1);
                   dispose();
                } catch (IOException ex){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error ! ");
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

This is the code I've tried to do above task . But unfortunately I couldn't complete it . Because when I send 'filepath.getPath()' to 'createZip()' method it is got just only  one directory at the time . But when I was printed filepath before the method calling it gave me following . ''NIO Folders 1122 : C:\Users\user\Desktop\backup ''-
'' NIO Folders 1122 : C:\Users\user\Desktop\contact''.

The reason I can think is, the applicartion is running without waiting for one thread to complete. Therefore all the threads are running in a loop. Below is my zipping code, which runs inside the above mentioned thread.

```
public void createZip(String directoryPath, String zipPath) throws IOException{
        value = countFilesInDirectory(new File(directoryPath));
        ExpressWizard.backupProgressBar.setMaximum(value);

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bOut = null;
        ZipArchiveOutputStream tOut = null;
        try{
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(zipPath));
            bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
            tOut = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(bOut);

            addFileToZip(tOut, directoryPath, "");

        } finally {
            tOut.finish();
            tOut.close();
            bOut.close();
            fOut.close();
        }

}

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
private void addFileToZip(ZipArchiveOutputStream zOut, String path, String base) throws IOException{
    File f = new File(path);
        String entryName = base + f.getName();
        ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry(f, entryName);

        zOut.putArchiveEntry(zipEntry);

        if (f.isFile()) {
            FileInputStream fInputStream = null;
            try{
                fInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                IOUtils.copy(fInputStream, zOut);
                zOut.closeArchiveEntry();
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(fInputStream);
            }
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            counter++;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    ExpressWizard.backupProgressBar.setValue(counter);
                    ExpressWizard.filesTextArea.append(f.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                }
            });

            if (ExpressWizard.backupProgressBar.getValue() == counter){
                ExpressWizard.backUpButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        } else{
            zOut.closeArchiveEntry();
            File[] children = f.listFiles();

            if (children != null){
                for (File child : children){
                    addFileToZip(zOut, child.getAbsolutePath(), entryName + "/");
                    System.out.println("File: " + child.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

How can I execute this code, one by one? In other words, the zip file thread should run for one folder; the loop should wait; when the zip is completes, the second folder starts zipping; The loop waits for the end of thread; then the third folder and so on.

Any ideas?